# Cannot get 'x' because property 'x' is missing in undefined

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have been trying to convert a functional React component from PropTypes to Flow. This component is given an object that contains strings to be used within the component.

Previously it looked similar to this:

```
Component.propTypes = {
  strings: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string),
}

Component.defaultProps = {
  strings: {
    key_one: "string one",
    key_two: "string two",
  }
}
```

I have converted this to:

```
type Props = {
  strings?: { [string_key: string]: string },
}

const Component = ({ strings }: Props) => (
  // component using 
  // label={strings.key_one}
  // etc
)

Component.defaultProps = {
  strings: {
    key_one: "string one",
    key_two: "string two",
  }
}
```

This produces the error:

```
Cannot get strings.key_one because property key_one is missing in undefined [1].

 [1] strings?: { [string_key: string]: string },
```

If I remove `[string_key: string]: ?string` it produces a second error message in addition to the first:

```
property key_one is missing in object type [1].
```

If I remove the optional marker then the error disappears, but then I cannot provide default props (`strings?: { [string_key: string]: string },` -> `strings: { [string_key: string]: string },`).

Reading issues it seems like this *might* be due to  [refinement invalidation](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) happening in the conversion from JSX, noted here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6350.

Can anyone shed any further light, and know if there is a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer to my own question. It is non-intuitive.

See the thread https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1660.

It looks like:

> You don’t need to make ... the prop ... optional in your Props type. Flow will
>   make sure that foo is optional if you have a default prop for foo.

Testing my existing tests do seem to pass - indicating that the default props specified are still captured in snapshots even when not marked with `?`. This works, but does reduce the use of `type Props =` in acting as documentation on its own.